# how to execute AWS CLI commands from Java code?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-java-sdk

How can I execute the following from Java code to get the S3 bucket size
`aws s3api list-objects --bucket BUCKETNAME --output json --query "[sum(Contents[].Size), length(Contents[])]"`

Comment: Java runtime allows you to cmds but why not use aws SDK?

Comment: @Shibashis CLI supports copy of prefixes, SDK does not, and the CLI seems much faster and simpler. There are thread pool concerns that are painful with the SDK that just evaporate with the CLI

Answer (score 0):

Java's ProcessBuilder class can call the AWS CLI from Java pretty easily :

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder( yourCliCommandWithArgs );
Process process = pb.start();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
... then consume the CLI output as input.
```

I would use AWS Java SDK, and the equivalent to list objects for one path would be

```
ListVersionsRequest listVersionsRequest = new ListVersionsRequest()
                .withBucketName( yourBucketName )
                .withDelimiter( pathDelimiter ).withPrefix( "your/path/" );
```

You might have better luck with the Cloudwatch API, it provides total bucket sizes through the CLI and SDK BucketSizeBytes . http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cloudwatch-monitoring.html

I use http://www.insight4storage.com/ from AWS Marketplace to track my AWS S3 storage usage trends by prefix, bucket or storage class over time.  Its easier than the CLI or SDK.